# Filter criteria Is After Today minus 1 day

Tags: marketing-cloud

In the filter criteria what does It means if I write;
Is After Today minus 1 day

Comment: > getdate() -1 would be my guess

Comment: I'd say `> convert(date, getDate()-1)`.  Filters assume the time is midnight for datetime fields.

Answer (score 0):

Filter criteria 'Is After Today minus 1 day' means today same as what Adam has added about filters (> convert(date, getDate()-1))